# ActiveStorage: NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

I have been investigating this issue for the past 2 days, I am running rails 5.3.2 and i have been trying to use active storage for a profile picture upload of users that are already created

My model looks like this:

```
MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :avatar
  ...
end
```

my controller:

```
class MyModelsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_my_model, only: %i[edit show update]
  ...
  def update
    authorize @my_model

    @my_model.avatar.attach(params[:my_model][:avatar])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @my_model.update(model_params)
        format.html { redirect_to my_model_url(@my_model), notice: 'My model was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @my_model }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @my_model.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  ...
  private

  def load_my_model
    @my_model = MyModel.find(params[:id])
  end
 end
```

it throws an error everytime on *this line*:

```
 @my_model.avatar.attach(params[:my_model][:avatar])
```

**The Error:**

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):

(erb):19:in `<main>'
app/controllers/my_models_controller.rb:38:in `block in update'
app/controllers/my_models_controller.rb:37:in `update'
```

The raw Parameters:

```
{
"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"*******REDACTED****", 
"my_model"=>
 {
  "name"=>"Bambam",
  "my_model_type"=>"",
  "country"=>"blue",
  "avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007fdd275ce3e0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/9p/llb8yydx59g535nqkbj0xv0w0000gp/T/RackMultipart20200201-7622-vp74wb.png>, @original_filename="undraw_instant_information_6755.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"hair_stylist[avatar]\"; filename=\"undraw_instant_information_6755.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">
 },
 "commit"=>"Update",
 "id"=>"2"
}
```

I tried:

- Reinstalling activestorage
- Moving it to different models and forms to see if it works and same issue
- I tried removing that line and just use: `@my_model.update(model_params)` to update and it throws the same error

I am really running out of ideas, any idea of what the issue is?

Comment: Show log of params on call controller action. It is like "Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"?", "?"=>"?"}

Comment: you don't  need call ```@my_model.avatar.attach(params[:my_model][:avatar])```. Just add permit ```:avatar``` on method ```model_params```

Comment: @thiaguerd even when i got rid of that, i get the same error, that was just one of the things i tried to make it work but no success

Comment: So sad. I would try just put 1/0 in method ```update``` , going to error page, with console in page I access params[..] and would test everything. I already tried to use the same rails version here and all works fine. If you want share your all code on a repo, I can try something.

Comment: Is there more to that stack trace? Are you overriding any key methods in the model like initialize? Are there any callbacks in the model?

Comment: Please do `params.inspect` after line `authorize @my_model` and see what you get there. Something's fishy with the params reaching there. Are you using `before_action` or any other such callback in your controller which probably is disturbing the params? Please also make sure you have permitted avatar because I guess that must be the main issue.

Comment: can you please post the full request log if possible ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a issue related to **rails credentials**.
if you just followed the active storage guide you might have configured a storage service provider at `config/storage.yml`. Regardless your using it as development storage service it will raise this exception when attaching files. For instance:

```
amazon:
  service: S3
    access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:aws][:access_key_id] %>
    secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:aws][:secret_access_key] %>
    region: us-east-1
    bucket: ...
```

So make sure you have rails credentials set, or change it to your environment variables.

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a bit old - asked over a year ago and with no follow up on the requests to log, so not certain that it will get a confirmed resolution. Still, at first blush, your answer looks viable! Cool.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this type of error during file uploading with S3, Simple create config/secrets.yml file and add few required details...like the one shown below -

```
development:
  secret_key_base: 
test:
  secret_key_base: 
production:
  secret_key_base:
```

and this should work out easily. USE `rake secret` to create app secret string and dump in this file.
Moreover, dont forget to **remove uncommented lines from storage.yml** file, Not sure what is the issue, but *keeping uncommented lines in `storage.yml` file create some issues*...better delete them all if not needed.